# Normal map issue?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, normal-map

So I've baked normals with a high poly mesh to a low poly mesh and the results of the normal map doesn't even show the divided parts of mesh, like the legs, hands, head, etc. But instead shows the normal map as a full square. Is this even good enough to even work with? I also feel like it lacks normal map details. I've used Smart UV Project to unwrap the mesh.

I've attached an image of mines and I've attached an image of what I'm trying to achieve. I would like to know where I went wrong.

Mines
[image]

Another Blender User
[image]

With Space Option set to Object

[image]

With Ray Distance set to 10.000

[image]

Comment: Are you working with a cage? What's the Ray distance?

Comment: No, I'm not working with a cage. It's not checked. & the Ray Distance is 0.000.

Comment: It'll help you get good answers if you upload the .blend file, but in few words, whenever I'm baking high to low, I copy the low to use it as a cage, then in edit mode, I click S twice and scale the cage only enough to cover both low and hight, this gives the best results, but if you're not using a cage, you should increase the ray distance, this tells blender how far should it project the rays in order to get coords, 0 I guess means automatic.

Comment: I realized the Space option was on tangent, so I put it on Object instead. Now it shows divided parts of the mesh, but I've realized it has almost orange-ish parts in the baked normals. Is this okay? I will show an image. I also switched the Space option back to Tangent and also put the ray distance to 10.000 and it shows much deeper baked normal details. Had it to 1.000, but didn't show enough. Is it safe to have the space option as object like the 3rd image above and work with it having some green? And/or is it even safe to work with the 4th image above as normals? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're using metric, 10.000 units means 10 meters! As I said the best results you can get with a cage, creating a cage is very easy, you already have your low poly model, normal maps save distance information on 3 axis, it's not meant to be viewed in 2D, looking at a normal map, you can't guess if it's good or bad, unless it's really off (the images you added are, specially the 10.000), save your self the frustration, duplicate the low poly, scale the mesh just enough to overlap both your models (high and low) and use it as a cage.